# Does IMAGE column affect query performance even if it's not included in the query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, index-tuning, varbinary, query-performance

Given the following table storing multiple milions of rows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[files]
(
  [ID]           UNIQUEIDENTIFIER CONSTRAINT [a] DEFAULT(NEWID()) NOT NULL,
  [OOUID]        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
  [UserID]       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
  [OID]          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
  [CTY]          INT NOT NULL,
  [CTP]          VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  [FileName]     NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  [Comment]      VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  [SZ]           INT NOT NULL,
  [WD]           INT NULL,
  [HE]           INT NULL,
  [Type]         INT NOT NULL,
  [BIN]          IMAGE NULL,
  [DEL]          TINYINT NOT NULL,
  [ADAT]         DATETIME NOT NULL,
  [CRB]          VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  [UPDAT]        DATETIME NOT NULL,
  [HDD]          VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  [ZZTIX]        INT NOT NULL,
  [TAGID]        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
  [FT]           DATETIME NULL,
  [UIOFG]        TINYINT NULL,
  [SRC]          INT NOT NULL,
  [RV]           RV NOT NULL,
  [TID]          VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK1] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED([ID] ASC) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80)
);  
GO  
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_files_OID]
ON [dbo].[files]([OID] ASC) 
WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_files_CTY]
ON [dbo].[files]([OID] ASC, [CTY] ASC, [Type] ASC, [DEL] ASC) 
WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_files_RV] ON [dbo].[files]
([RV] ASC, [CTP] ASC, [TID] ASC)
INCLUDE([ID]) 
WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY];    

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_files_SZ]
ON [dbo].[files]([OID] ASC, [CTY] ASC, [DEL] ASC, [SZ] ASC) 
WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90);    

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_files_TID]
ON [dbo].[files]([TID] ASC);    

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_files_CTP_RV]
ON [dbo].[files]([CTP] ASC, [RV] ASC)
INCLUDE([ID], [DEL]);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_files_ID]
ON [dbo].[files]([ID] ASC)
INCLUDE([OID], [SZ]);
```

and the folllowing query:

```
Select files.ID, 
    files.FileName, 
    files.SZ, 
    files.FT, 
    files.OID, 
    files.Type,
    files.CTP,
    files.Comment
From files
Where files.OID IN (Select ID From dbo.anotherTable)
Order By files.OID
```

this query returns 1.6 Mio rows and is pretty slow (01:00 Min on executing it locally & saving results to file) and indicates a lot of IO:

> Table 'files (object1 in plan)'. Scan count
>   540481, logical reads 4659179, physical reads 14637, read-ahead reads
>   240400, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead
>   reads 0.
>
> Table 'object3'. Scan count 1, logical reads 33, physical
>   reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads
>   0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'object2'. Scan count 1, logical
>   reads 46096, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads
>   0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 13453 ms,  elapsed time =
>   144232 ms. SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms,
>   elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

The above information was not taken from the first execution so I made use of datacache as much as possible for fair comparison.

The most expensive part is the Clustered Index Seek operation.

> [Open Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy-2uPazl)

Then to improve that I tried creation of a covering nonclustered index:

```
Create Nonclustered index _ix_test on dbo.files 
(OID) include (ID,FileName,SZ,FT,Type,CTP,Comment)
```

After that the same query performs an nonclustered index SCAN using this new index.

> [Open new Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyS0iwaMx)

The IO statistics now say:

> Table 'file (object1)'. Scan count 1, logical reads 177674, physical reads
>   23, read-ahead reads 2235, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0,
>   lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'object3'. Scan count 1, logical
>   reads 33, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0,
>   lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'object2'. Scan
>   count 1, logical reads 46096, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0,
>   lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 9094 ms,  elapsed time =
>   55256 ms.
>
> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms,
>   elapsed time = 0 ms.

But although this ins an improvement, runtime still is 00:54 Min.

Not really a success...

I was hoping to see an index seek instead.
The table's / indexes statistics show that there us a very high percentage of three OID's - is this the reason not to seek the index?

After all I wonder why it is that slow in general? As you can see this problematic table contains an IMAGE column where BLOBS are stored. I am aware of this problematic architecture and working on a change. But meanwhile I wonder if  (and why) this BLOB may have bad influence on the query performance even if it is not at all included in the query?

Bytes per cluster (returned by `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo`) is 4096.

#### Results of Waits

```
WaitType ASYNC_NETWORK_IO Wait_S 44.69 Res_S 38.68 signal_S 6.01 WCnt 92961 Perc 48.97%                  
WaitType PREEMPTIVE_OS_WAITFORSINGLEOBJECT Wait_S 43.59 Res_S 43.59 Signal_s 0.00 WCnt 92527 Perc 47.77%
```

Comment: -Paste the execution plan
-Paste the whole IO and Time statistics
-is this first run or second run of the query (buffering pages from drvie to memory maybe?)

Comment: If you're returning data to the client, it's waiting for that which is why you aren't seeing a large decrease in time. Choose to return no data to the client and see how long it takes. Also, if you're returning 1.6 million rows, depending on the index a scan is most likely more efficient.

Comment: very low fillfactors. are the statistics updated on both tables? if you do an `inner join` instead of `IN`, `with option(recompile)` does it change anything?

Comment: @SeanGallardy how do I suppress returning the data to my client?

Comment: @VladislavZalesak I added the requested information. The results are nover beased on the first run so buffer is used.

Comment: @marcellomiorelli using OPTION(RECOMPILE)  did not change a lot regarding io statistics, exec plan or execution time.

Comment: 1.6M rows, UUID as the CI )or NCI index), 1 minute: does not look slow to me. Why would 1.6M index seeks perform better?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ maybe you are right, the root cause of anylyzing the query is that it sometimes caused an "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown" error that made me spend time to look after it.

Comment: @marcellomiorelli statistics update does not improve (are updated anyway once a week if necessary)

Comment: There is a typo (extra comma) in the query code: `From files,`

Comment: Regarding the query: do you have a non-clustered index on `dbo.anotherTable (ID)`? And why the plan shows 3 objects when the query involves only 2 tables? Is this the actual query that produced the plan?

Comment: "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown" is caused by an issue on the client for SSMS, typically when you try to return a result set that's too large. It is not a sign of a performance problem with a SQL Server query.

Answer (score 1):

## Wait Statistics

Seeing as we have to find out where SQL Server is waiting (if it is actually SQL Server) you will have to have a look at the Wait Statistics.

There is some code you can download from Paul Randal's SQLSkills.com site which provides you with the means to analyse the wait statistics.

[Capturing wait statistics for a period of time](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/capturing-wait-statistics-period-time/)

1. Instead of just running the code and modifying the delay period, open up a Query window and execute the first portion of the SQL statement up until the `WAITFOR DELAY '00:30:00';` part.
2. Then execute whatever you have to do.
3. After the query has executed run the second part of Paul's script to output the differences found. (The part after the `WAITFOR DELAY '00:30:00';`)

Depending on the wait statistics you find in the results, you can find hints of what may be the issue in the [SQL Server Wait Types Library](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits) on Paul's site.

Then go from there. Depending on your wait stats, you should see what your SQL Server is waiting for. If you don't find any big issues, then your application might be the limiting factor.

## Disk Alignement

Seeing as you had many read aheads without the covering index, you might want to verify that your data disks are formatted with 64k block size. SQL Server reads in Extents which is explained in the [Reading Pages](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191475(v=sql.105).aspx) information on Microsoft's site. (1 Extent = 8 Pages = 64kB)

You can also find information about disk alignment on Microsoft's [Disk Partition Alignment Best Practices for SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758814(v=sql.100).aspx). This document will also explain how to retrieve the block size with the command:

```
fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo c:
```

Results will look similar to this (check the **bytes per cluster** value)

```
NTFS Volume Serial Number :       0xa2060a7f060a54a7
Version :                         3.1
Number Sectors :                  0x00000000043c3f5f
Total Clusters :                  0x000000000008787e
Free Clusters  :                  0x000000000008746e
Total Reserved :                  0x0000000000000000
Bytes Per Sector  :               512
Bytes Per Cluster :               65536
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    : 1024
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment : 0
Mft Valid Data Length :           0x0000000000010000
Mft Start Lcn  :                  0x000000000000c000
Mft2 Start Lcn :                  0x0000000000043c3f
Mft Zone Start :                  0x000000000000c000
Mft Zone End   :                  0x000000000001cf20
```

Having the MDF/NDF and LDF files on 64k formatted drives can help improve performance regarding read ahead speed.

> An appropriate value for most installations should be 65,536 bytes (that is, 64 KB) for partitions on which SQL Server data or log files reside. In many cases, this is the same size for Analysis Services data or log files, but there are times where 32 KB provides better performance. To determine the right size, you will need to do performance testing with your workload comparing the two different block sizes.

You should be able to pinpoint some of your performance issues with these guidelines.

> Disclaimer: I am in no way affiliated with Microsoft, Paul Randall, or SQLSkills.com.

Comment: Results of Waits:
WaitType ASYNC_NETWORK_IO Wait_S 44.69 Res_S 38.68 signal_S 6.01 WCnt 92961 Perc 48.97%                  
WaitType PREEMPTIVE_OS_WAITFORSINGLEOBJECT Wait_S 43.59 Res_S 43.59 Signal_s 0.00 WCnt 92527 Perc 47.77%

Comment: This wait type is never indicative of a problem with SQL Server, and the vast majority of the time it is nothing to do with the network either [...]
There is nothing that you can do with your SQL Server code that will affect this wait type. There are a few causes of this on the client side, including: -> The client code is doing what is known as RBAR (Row-By-Agonizing-Row), where only one row at a time is pulled from the results and processed, instead of caching all the results and then immediately replying to SQL Server and proceeding to process the cached rows
[...] SQLSkills.com